# datepicker not disabled before certain date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I ma using jquery Datepicker and for the photo of the day(checkbox) I am using datepicker such that when user clicks certain date for certain photo that date will be disabled in another photo of the day(checkbox). It's working all fine but the date is being disabled only after 10 and not before it.Why?
Below is my code:]

**HTML**

```
<div class="photos">
<div class="photooftheday">
  <input class="photo_of_the_day" type="checkbox" value="5/14" name="photoday[]">
  Photo of the Day
</div>
<input class="datepicker photoDate2" type="text" style="display:none;" name="date[]" value="">
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input.photo_of_the_day').live('click', function(){
  var array = [];
  var used_dates = $('input#date_photos').val(); // dates from database
  var useddates = used_dates.split(','); 
  for(var i=0; i < useddates.length; i++) {
      array.push(useddates[i]);
   }
// array  = 2013-10-30,2013-10-22,2013-10-21,2013-10-29,2013-10-28,2013-10-20,2013-10-29 when alerted
   var parents = $(this).parents('div.photos');
   $('input.datepicker:visible').each(function(){
       var val = $(this).val();
        array.push(val);
   })
    var unavailableDates = array;
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
                parents.find('input.datepicker').css('display', 'block');
                parents.find('input.datepicker').val('');
                parents.find('input.datepicker').datepicker({
                    "dateFormat":"yy-mm-dd",
                    "minDate":0,
                    "beforeShowDay": function(date){
                        dmy = date.getFullYear()+ "-" +(date.getMonth() + 1)+ "-" +date.getDate();
                        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
                            return [true, ""];
                        } else {
                            return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                parents.find('input.datepicker').css('display', 'none');
            }
        })
</script>
```

Any help or suggestions is welcome. Thanks

Comment: `Unclear` what are you asking? Tried some code on http://jsfiddle.net/2wHbY/

Comment: @RohanKumar [http://jsfiddle.net/2wHbY/]{http://jsfiddle.net/2wHbY/}
check this. I have multiple checkboxes,now when i choose some date say 10 it should be disabled when i check another checkbox.My problem is the date checked before 10 isn't being disabled while date checked after 10 is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution. Problem is for date less than 10 value is returned as 01,02 when clicked and so on whereas to check for the unavailable dates value is 1,2 and so on. so I updated the above jquery code as follows:

```
$('input.photo_of_the_day').live('click', function(){
            var array = [];
            var used_dates = $('input#date_photos').val(); // db dates
            var useddates = used_dates.split(','); 
            for(var i=0; i < useddates.length; i++) {
                array.push(useddates[i]);
            }
            var parents = $(this).parents('div.photos');
            $('input.datepicker:visible').each(function(){
                var val = $(this).val();
                array.push(val);
            })
            var unavailableDates = array;
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                parents.find('input.datepicker').css('display', 'block');
                parents.find('input.datepicker').val('');
                parents.find('input.datepicker').datepicker({
                    "dateFormat":"yy-mm-dd",
                    "minDate":0,
                    "beforeShowDay": function(date){
                        var Date = (date.getDate() < 10) ? '0'+date.getDate() : date.getDate();  // added this
                        dmy = date.getFullYear()+ "-" +(date.getMonth() + 1)+ "-" + Date;
                        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
                            return [true, ""];
                        } else {
                            return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                parents.find('input.datepicker').css('display', 'none');
            }
        })
```